# How to flag a low quality answer in such a way the community can decide if this has to be deleted or not?

Tags: discussion, flagging

It happens sometimes to flag an answer like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1149001/121097) as a low quality answer, and the moderators say "declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".
I'd like to flag these answers in such a way the community decide to delete it or not, without the intervention of the mods (even not making them aware of such things, if possible). Is this possible?

Comment: This is a good question in that I don't know the best course of action. The handling of the accuracy of content is **not** moderators' job, so I quite understand the flag getting declined. The answer never spent any time in the review queue (I don't know why). At least I didn't see any evidence of that in the timeline. I don't know to what extent matters are further complicated by the fact that this answer has been accepted.

Comment: We the moderators do make a call if a post comes back from the review queue with mixed response. An option (for you) is to earn the delete privilege (in due time). Another option is to bring the offending post to the notice of the users in Reopen/Undelete/Close/Delete chatroom.

Comment: [Somewhat relevant](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10133/should-moderators-intervene-when-the-accepted-answer-is-blatantly-wrong).

Comment: Personally, I would love the ability to flag directly into the Low Quality queue.

Comment: @Arkamis I do not quite get what it is that you want. When one flags a post as very low quality *usually* it goes directly to the LQQ.

Comment: I want it to perhaps be more usually ;)

Comment: @Arkamis, you have earned the privilege to vote to delete, so what do you need the LQQ for? Answers with delete votes can be found from the Tools menu by other users with the relevant privilege. Downvote and vote to delete.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usually, if you flag an answer as "not an answer" or "very low quality", the answer gets into the review queue, where the reviewers can decide to recommend deletion or vote to delete (if they have 20k reputation and not yet used all their delete votes for the day). The reviewers may base their judgment also on the correctness (or incorrectness, rather) of the answer, but they may also base their judgment only on formal criteria.

Accepted answers however do not enter the review queues when flagged, and moderators are not supposed to take the correctness of an answer into account when evaluating flags.

So flagging accepted answers with the aim to have them deleted can only succeed when the answer has problems beyond being wrong.

If you want the community to deal with such answers, you need to directly inform trusted users (users with at least 20k rep), e.g. in the [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) or in the [CRUDE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/reopen-undelete-close-delete) room.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing: a flagged answer like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1146132/121097) was considered by the mods (I think) as "disputed". What this exactly means? (I think this was in the review queue.)

Comment: That one went into the [review queue](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/353187), and the reviewers disagreed with the flag. No moderators involved. Note that since recently [or soon, not sure if already implemented], if the reviewers unanimously choose "Looks OK", the flag will be declined instead of disputed. (Not that a declined flag is a big deal.)

Comment: @Daniel How did you find the review task associated with the post? Is it a special moderator tool, or is it something us *normals* can do?

Comment: @Meelo If you have access to the review queue, you can find the review task also as an ordinary user. If you know _when_ it was reviewed to within an hour or so, it even is not too bad (review->queue->history, look for the question title). Moderators have it more comfortable, if a post was reviewed, there is a link to the review task in the moderator timeline.

Comment: Nit-pick (or I miss something): having *access to the queue* is not sufficient; to see the entire history is 10k+, below that one only gets one's own reviews (not all) under history.

Comment: Ah, @quid is of course right. I forgot that criterion.

Comment: I will add to the above comments that a rather comfortable way to find a review is to [look at the timeline of the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1146132/timeline) - but the review is shown there only *after* it is finished. For some basic info about timeline, including the way to access it, see [the corresponding tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/timeline/info),